# BufferedMediaTypeFormatter HttpContent does not contain all Headers sent in Request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, owin

Within my Owin Self hosted Web Api project I am trying to build a `custom MediaTypeFormatter` that inherits from `BufferedMediaTypeFormatter`.
But the problem is the `HttpContent` object passed into `ReadFromStream(..)` does not contain all the headers sent in the request.

How do you access ALL the headers that were sent in the request (I know this because I made the request), or access the original `HttpRequestMessage` in the `ReadFromStream(..)` method ?

This seams to be a major bug and I cannot think of any reason why all the `Request` headers are not provided.

Comment: Can you be more specific what headers are not available in HTTPContent? Am trying to create a sample and not seeing any header that is not coming through.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the ASP.NET Request object does not expose a property for the specific header field name you are looking for.

So it looks like first, you need the Request and to do that you might be able to override `GetPerRequestFormatterInstance`:

[How do I retrieve the HTTP request method in an ASP.NET WebAPI MediaTypeFormatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859826/how-do-i-retrieve-the-http-request-method-in-an-asp-net-webapi-mediatypeformatte)

Once you have the request object you can search for the specific header field name you are looking for like so:

```
IEnumerable<string> headerValues = request.Headers.GetValues("MyHeaderFieldName");
var id = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
```

You can also get the raw request if needed:

```
Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
var input = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Within BufferedMediaTypeFormatter there is no object in scope that represents the request, so all your examples are not relevant.

Comment: Well it seems then your question is one step ahead of your starting point. You need the request so google "access request in BufferedMediaTypeFormatter"

Comment: I updated my answer perhaps you can override GetPerRequestFormatterInstance to get the request object for the current request

Comment: Once again, you do not read the question. GetPerRequestFormatterInstance is for writing the response out, because you pass in the HttpRequestMessage to it. I am wanting to get the headers of the Request so that I can properly implement ReadFromStream.