# how to get an array of numbers from angular.js resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my RESTful API returns an array:

```
GET /test => [1367297123312,1.0,2.0,3.0,100]
```

I have a service:

```
(angular
 .module('app.services', ['ng', 'ngResource'])
 .factory('myData', [
     /******/ '$resource',
     function ($resource) {
         return $resource('test');
     }])
);
```

In my controller I need to get the numbers. I tried:

```
(angular
 .module('app.controllers', ['ng', 'app.services'])
 .controller('tweetsapiContr', [
     /******/ '$scope', 'myData',
     function ($scope,   myData) {
         myData.get({}, function (data) {
             console.log(data);
         };
     }
 ])
);
```

The above gives me `TypeError: Object #<h> has no method 'push'` error, and if I use `query` instead of `get` on the service, it returns an array of objects that have methods like `$get`, `$save` etc, but calling `$get` for example returns `undefined`.

How to get the numbers? Responding with a hash from the server works, but I am trying to figure out how to make it work with arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This open issue (#4314)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4314) has good information about why numbers (and other primitive data types like strings) cannot be parsed by `$resource`.

From what I understand, $resource needs to work on objects so that it can attach it's methods (`get`, `query`, `post`, etc...).  If all you are trying to do is to read the array and never need to 'update' it, they recommend using just straight up `$http`.

Hope that helps clear things up and points future readers of this question in the right direction for best practices in dealing with arrays over a REST api.

Answer (score 8):

> A resource "class" object with methods for the default set of resource actions optionally > extended with custom `actions`. The default set contains these actions:

```
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

So you have two options:

### Set a custom method on the resource object:

```
$resource("/url/:someParam", {}, {
    getMyArray: {method:"GET", params: {someParam:"hello"}, isArray: true}
});
```

### Use query method

Resource object has a `query` method which is defined with `isArray: true` as you can see in the top of the answer.

Please be advised that responding with a top level array to a `GET` method has security vulnerabilities as array constructors can be redefined.

Read those: 
[JSON security best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395592/json-security-best-practices)
[What are "top level JSON arrays" and why are they a security risk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503102/what-are-top-level-json-arrays-and-why-are-they-a-security-risk)

Answer (score 5):

You can add a custom action to the resource with isArray: true; ([resource docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource))

```
return $resource('test', {}, {
  getArray: { method: 'GET', isArray: true } 
};
```

Then I believe you have to call it with a dollar sign `myData.$getArray`

Comment: I don't think you are using it correctly, when you call resource get the object should evaluate to your data. Try `var myArray = myData.query(); console.log(myArray)`

Comment: this won't work because the resource returns a promise object which is populated later when the response comes back.

Answer (score 2):

You should not return JSON arrays since they are vulnerable to cross site attacks. Read this article for the *why* part http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx

Return an object with the array attached to a property. This will mitigate potential attacks and solve your problem in one go.

```
{
    d: [1,2,3,4,5]
}


myData.get({}, function (data) {
    console.log(data.d);
};
```

---

#### Still want the array?

You can restructure the actions of a resource and set the isArray property of the action to `true`.

[Angular ngResource docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

```
var actions = { 
  'get':    {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} 
};

$resource(url[, paramDefaults][, actions]);
```

Comment: yes, I have read the article before. I am still interested to figure out how to fetch arrays. I think this is not a problem with arrays, but with the numbers.

Comment: i also think there is some problem with handling numbers