# Backbone.js Collection fetching security

Tags: json, api, security, backbone.js

When fetching Backbone.js Collections from an API, Backbone expects a JSON array:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "whatever"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "another"
    }
]
```

I guess this is a security risk, see: [JSON security best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395592/json-security-best-practices)

I would like to make Backbone understand the following format:

```
{
    things: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "whatever"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "another"
        }
    ]
}
```

I there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: Did you try reading the [Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse)?

Comment: I did, but I was also wondering if there where more people having these security concerns and if there is a "best practice" for this in Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  parse: function(response) { // This is called after the `fetch()` got its data
    return response.things;
  }
});
```

However I don't see any security threat using simple array..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503102/what-are-top-level-json-arrays-and-why-are-they-a-security-risk