# Grape route with array as root object

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm defining params for a grape route like this

```
    params do
      requires :array, type: Array do
          requires :foo, type: String
          requires :bar, type: String
      end
    end
```

The data for this endpoint would be `{"array": [{"foo": "123", "bar": "456"}]}`.

> How can I get rid of the additional `"array"`? The data should look like this `[{"foo": "123", "bar": "456"}]`

I can't define a type `Array` on `params`.

Comment: I think most DSL's skip this because of vulnerabilities (as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/395592/3109182 )

Comment: ok, that makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use groups to do this, more info at 
https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#group-options

e.g.:
    params do
      group :array, type: Array do
        requires :foo, type: String
        requires :bar, type: String
        ...
      end
    end