# Which one is efficient JSON or XML in case of Server client J2EE applications?

Tags: jquery, xml, json

I am using Jquery in my J2EE application. I am still using XML to get pass and get the data from the server. My client side code is very vague to see. Is it better to move from XML to JSON ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There have been big discussions about `XML` vs. `JSON`. Speaking in performance, there is actually no way around `JSON`. Its just so well `recognized` by JavaScript. Parsing & Encoding is way way faster than `XML`.

Still, there is a right to exist for `XML`. If you got very large datastructures with lots of information for instance, `XML` might be a better choice.

So I think it really depends on what kind of data structure you want to transfer, but in general, I'd always prefer `JSON` for server->client (javascript) data transfer.

Further read: [When to prefer JSON over XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325085/when-to-prefer-json-over-xml)